# how to fix networkerror when fetching an api?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to fetch an Api, but it keeps telling me there is a network error and I cant find a way anywhere to fix it.

```
const atlasApi = `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://atlas-obscura-api.herokuapp.com/api/atlas/destinations`
fetch(atlasApi).then(response => {
  return response.json()
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your api url seems incorrect, please try removing Access-Control-Allow-Origin: from the atlasApi. Then it should work fine.

Comment: I dont thinks its that bcuz when i remove that i get a cors error and the network error also stays. but when i add access-control-allow-origion it takes away the cors error.

Comment: you should include that in headers